# Renew iOS Distribution Certificates

Tags: ios, certificate

I need to renew my iOS Distribution certificate for my mobile app and want to hire a freelancer to do it for me.

I know, this needs to be done with the Apple Developer Account - however I do not wish to give him root access. Whats the best possible way to do it?

Appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: don't give your account, just add the developer as a Developer in Users and Access tab in the App Store Connect site.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to give the hired developers a full access to your **Apple Developer Account** to allow them to develop an app for you and/or renew any kind of certificates in your account. Just ask the developer's email and add it in `Users and Access` section by assigning a proper role on the Apple Developer Website. In your case, you can assign the role of either `App Manager` or `Developer` to a hired freelancer, it depends on how much access you want to give them. You can read more about possible roles in [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/)